# div containing resized image, width are not resized to width of image

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with a `fixed` `position` containing an image that I have set to `max-width:20%` so it is scaled down. The `height` of the `div` is scaled to match the image but the `width` isn't, it looks like it's the same `width` of the initial size of the image.

I might be missing something fundamental but can't really understand this.

```css
#logo {
  max-width: 20%;
}

#logoholder {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 120px;
  background: rgb(47 47 47 / 36%);
  text-align: center;
}

#logo2 {
  max-width: 77px;
}

#logoholder2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 30px;
  background: rgb(47 47 47 / 36%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoholder">
  <img id="logo" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/static-2.0/images/logo-gmail.png">
</div>

<-- Expected result -->
<div id="logoholder2">
  <img id="logo2" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/static-2.0/images/logo-gmail.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand the problem as you have set text-align: center so the logo moves to the center of its container. And it is 20% the width of its container (you haven't set a width for logoholder so it's gone to default). i.e it is doing what is expected.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the ultimate goal/motivation behind the `position: fixed;` as there may be an alternative with less issues.

Comment: It's for a button at fixed position on the page and need to resize image but keep ratio thats why I tried max-width X %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#logo{
  max-width:100px;
}

#logoholder {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background: rgb(47 47 47 / 36%);
}
```

```html
<div id="logoholder">
<img id="logo" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/static-2.0/images/logo-gmail.png">
</div>
```

The `max-width` using a percentage is causing weird behaviour, changed it to px.

Comment: Yes that works, just need to calculate ratio instead with javascript

Comment: with jquery $("#logo").width($("#logo").width() * 0.2);

Answer (score 0):

I set some margins and borders for clarity - and left the original images in place (the first one is the one in play here)

I would suggest using a flex display for simplicity then we can set the container to a size and the height of the image to what we want relative to that (see comments in the CSS)

I set the button at the "top" but it could be relative position also and work around that "fixed" position issue.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#logoholder {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 1rem;
  /*  background: rgb(47 47 47 / 36%);*/
  /* light violet background */
  background-color: #8080FF20;
}

#logo {
  max-width: 20%;
}

#logoholder2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 30px;
  */ width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  /* light cyan background */
  background-color: #20E0E020;
}

#logo2 {
  max-width: 77px;
}


/* set up the blocks to keep the "gray" one at the top */

.container-all {
  display: flex;
  align-items: cemter;
  justify-content: cemter;
  /*stack then for this demo */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* the "lime" border around all the content */
  border: solid 1px #88ff88;
}

.container-all .content-container {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  /* get our logo (first container) at the top if we want to */
  /* margin-top:0;*/
}

.logo-container {
  /* keep logo/button at top when scrolling for this demo */
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* set up this containers display */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-container .content-item {
  /* controls the height of the image on the button */
  /* these should be the same since the "default" is 16px font-size == 1rem */
  font-size: 1rem;
  /*  font-size:16px;*/
}

.logo-image {
  /* controlled by container font size as these have em */
  /* so if 1rem = 16px this 4em would be 16 X 5=80px */
  height: 5em;
}

.content-container {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.content-container:first-of-type {
  /* light gray background for this demo */
  /* alpha transparency information into the hex format for colors 2E as this has 8 characters */
  background-color: #8080802E;
  border: outset #D0D0D02E 4px;
}

.content-item {
  border: dashed #00000044 1px;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

.content-container .content-item .big-me:last-of-type {
  height: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-all">
  <div class="logo-container content-container">
    <button type="button" class="content-item">
      <img class="logo-image" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/static-2.0/images/logo-gmail.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-item">
      Below here just to force scrolling on the sticky icon
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="logoholder" class="xcontent-container">
    <div class="content-item">
      <img id="logo" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/static-2.0/images/logo-gmail.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-item">
      &lt;-- Expected result --&gt;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="logoholder2" class="content-container">
    <div class="content-item">
      <img id="logo2" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/static-2.0/images/logo-gmail.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-item">
      <div class="big-me">I am big so I can force the scroll.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```